# Происхождение "власть имущих"

Tags: фразеология

Есть ли первоисточник у этого выражения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вряд ли. Это просто устаревшее официальное  выражение = власть имеющие. Своеобразное  клише для обозначения тех, в чьих руках находится власть; в наше время употребляется в ироническом смысле: у них власть, они должны употребить её на пользу государству, а они используют для личных целей, не исполняют свой долг государственного человека. Имеют власть  =  имеют богатство, имущие.